# Installer Win Forms Application with SQL Server 2014 Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, deployment

I have developed an application with VB.Net and SQL Express 2014. I have created a installer using inno setup. The Database files (mdf & ldf) are bundled along with the installer and are installed in a separate DB folder with 'Full' access rights.

The connection string is as follows:

```
 <add name="MyApp.My.MySettings.MyAppConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Program Files\MyAppDB\MyApp.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am using the SQL Server as a Local Instance application with Windows Authentication without login id & password for the sql server.

The installation is usually done by a person from the IT dept with Admin rights but when the intended user uses it refuses to connect to the server as the user does not have the rights. If the user is made as an administrator then the application is able to connect to the SQL Server. (Of course, the SQL Server needs to 'Security' permissions to be given manually thru windows explorer file properties menu - the user has to be 'added up' to the list of permitted users with 'Full Control').

But in some instances  the IT dept refuses to give the user the 'Admin' credentials and it becomes a security issue.

I tried googling for some time and found info, but just could not solve the issue of the app + sql server working for a 'non-admin' user who has not installed the app..

Hope I have explained it enough..

Kindly help me to over come this issue..

Thanks
Renga

Comment: When you say it refuses to connect - what is the error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the installation directory to the user/appdata? even if it's just for the DB.
This may resolve any conflicting user rights.
You can use these following enviroment variables in inno setup for the locations.

```
C:\Users\user>echo %userprofile%
C:\Users\user

C:\Users\user>echo %appdata%
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming
```

Answer (score 0):

It is conceptually incorrect to put database files into `Program Files` directory. The latter is intended for unchanged content, such as applications' binaries. The database will probably be changed continuously, and even if it is used in the 100% read-only mode there will be some changes.

When I happened upon the same problem for my own project not so long ago, I have settled on `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` directory. It specifically targets data files common for all users, and as such have very relaxed permissions by default.

Unless you need to perform multiple per-user installations on the same machine, it will be an ideal candidate to place database files into.